# Accessing multiple form controls from class at once

Tags: c#

I was recently looking for a way to access, let's say, a textbox on my form from class.

I found a way of doing it (for example changing text in textbox) like so:

```
MyClass c1 = new Myclass();
c1.method(textBox1);
```

And the class:

```
class MyClass
{
     public void method(Object obj)
     {
         (obj as TextBox).Text = "a";
     }
}
```

My 2 questions:

- Is this a proper way of doing this?
- Can I access multiple textboxes at once some way, without passing 20 textboxes as arguments to my method?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you pass `Object` instead of `Textbox`?

Comment: I just found out about this way, did it like they said in the guide. I'm kinda new to the programming.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you could probably pass an array of TextBoxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass reference of your `form` to access all of its controls:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void method(Form1 objForm)
    {
        (objForm.Controls.Find("textBox1", true)[0] as TextBox).Text = "1";
        (objForm.Controls.Find("textBox2", true)[0] as TextBox).Text = "2";
        (objForm.Controls.Find("textBox3", true)[0] as TextBox).Text = "3";
    }
}
```

To use this code, you'll just pass the reference of the form:

```
MyClass c1 = new Myclass();
c1.method(this);
```

**Explanation:**

The method will take the reference of original `form`'s object. Then it'll search in the controls list of the `form` for the specified control, and will pick the first item of the array. After that, it'll cast that item into the `TextBox` (because the item we searched for has the type `TextBox`) and then will set its property value.

Comment: It says that my objForm does not contain definition of textBox1 and no extension method textBox1

Comment: It won't work if the TextBoxes are in a different control, like a Panel.  What if they are all in **different** containers too?  Change `false` to `true` to fix this.

Comment: Very nice observation. I didn't think about it. Thank you